# Stripped rows with no table - children divs inside divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

I would like to have stripped rows with "complex" children. I can't figure out how to do this.
I use bootstrap, not sure if it makes any difference, i guess no ;)

Here is what I do: 
[https://jsfiddle.net/1w9tv4ce/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/1w9tv4ce/)
I want all `test-01` to be green for exemple, then `test-02` black, `test-03` green, `test-04` black.

```css
.rows-search div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #95CA44;
}

.rows-search div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
}

.search-light-grey {
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container search-light-grey">
  <div class="rows-search">
    <div id="1">
      test-01
      <div>
        1
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          2a
        </div>
        <div>
          2b
        </div>
        <div>
          2c
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">test-02</div>
    <div id="3">test-03</div>
    <div id="4">test-04</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use the `>` selector - means direct children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use child combinator ([**`>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)) in your selectors (this will only target *immediate* child elements) - see demo below:

```css
.rows-search > div:nth-child(even) { /* <-- changed */
  background-color: #95CA44;
}

.rows-search > div:nth-child(odd) { /* <-- changed */
  background-color: black;
}

.search-light-grey {
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container search-light-grey">
  <div class="rows-search">
    <div id="1">
      test-01
      <div>
        1
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          2a
        </div>
        <div>
          2b
        </div>
        <div>
          2c
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">test-02</div>
    <div id="3">test-03</div>
    <div id="4">test-04</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, use the `>` selector - means direct children

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

```css
.rows-search > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #95CA44;
}

.rows-search > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
}

.search-light-grey {
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container search-light-grey">
  <div class="rows-search">
    <div id="1">
      test-01
      <div>
        1
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          2a
        </div>
        <div>
          2b
        </div>
        <div>
          2c
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">test-02</div>
    <div id="3">test-03</div>
    <div id="4">test-04</div>
  </div>
</div>
```